# tensorflow - implementing experience replay memory with the estimator api

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, tensorflow-estimator

I try to implement an [experience replay memory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.01783.pdf) with the [tf.estimator.Estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator) API. However, i am not sure what is the best way to achieve a result which works atleast for all modes (`TRAIN`, `EVALUATE`, `PREDICT`). I tried the following:

- Implement the memory with a `tf.Variable`, which causes issues with the batching and the input pipeline (i cannot input a custom experience in testing or prediction phase)

and currently try to:

- Implement the memory outside the `tf.Graph`. Set the values after each run with a `tf.train.SessionRunHook`. Load the experiences with `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()` during training and testing. Manage the state on your own.

I am failing on several points and starting to believe that the tf.estimator.Estimator API does not provide me with the necessary interfaces to easily write this down.

Some code (first approach, which fails with the batch_size, since it is fixed for the slicing of the exp, i cannot use the model for prediction or evaluation):

```
 def model_fn(self, features, labels, mode, params):
    batch_size = features["matrix"].get_shape()[0].value

    # get prev_exp
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        erm = tf.get_variable("erm", shape=[30000, 10], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(self.erm.initial_train_erm()), trainable=False)
        prev_exp = tf.slice(erm, [features["index"][0], 0], [batch_size, 10])

    # model
    pred = model(features["matrix"], prev_exp, params)
```

However: it would be better to have the erm inside the feature dict. But then i have to manage the erm outside the graph and also write back my newest experience with a SessionRunHook. Is there any better way or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by implementing the ERM outside the graph, feeding it back into the input pipeline with tf.data.Dataset.from_generator() and writing back by using SessionRunHooks. Yeah, pretty tedious but it is working.